# IJCADでパレットに配置したテキストボックスのEnter入力がフックできません

Tags: ijcad, vb.net

VBを使用してIJCAD2023のパレットを作成しています。
パレット上にテキストボックスを配置して、テキストボックス内でEnterキーが押されたかチェックするために、KeyDown、PreviewKeyDownをフックしましたが、イベントが発生しません。
Enterキーが押されたことを判別することはできないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

> パレット上にテキストボックスを配置して、テキストボックス内でEnterキーが押されたかチェックするために、KeyDown、PreviewKeyDownをフックしましたが、イベントが発生しません。
> Enterキーが押されたことを判別することはできないでしょうか。

ご提示の通り、目的の動作を実現するためには、
Control.KeyDownイベントおよびControl.PreviewKeyDownイベントで達成可能と考えられます。